# BLDC max speed KV or Hz?

Tags: frequency, electromagnetism, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, phase

So from what I've understood, the KV rating for a motor gives us the rotor speed based on the voltage applied at the phase of the motor.
Having looked a bit deeper in ESC / inverters, I've come up with the conclusion that it's rather the frequency of phase commuting that sets the motor's speed.

But I guess there is some electromagnetic force (lorentz / laplace?) that defines the force exerted on a body knowing the voltage flowing through it.

What I'm thinking is that the frequency commuting defines speed, but the current/volts going through each coil defines the maximum force/acceleration the rotor can be pulled with. And since commuting is done one zero-crossing of the floating phase, this max acceleration (thus time it gets to do the zero-xing) limits the commuting freq.

Could anyone help me to figure this out ?

Comment: Laplace has nothing to do with magnetics and voltage doesn't flow through anything.

Comment: My bad, it's called Lorentz in english.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force
Voltage flow => Sure, current flows but U=RI ?
I do my homework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider both frequency and Kv in driving a BLDC motor, and motor drivers differ in how they take this into account. So, both points are correct.

The rotational speed is directly related to the commutation frequency and the pole count.

And Kv * rotational speed gives you the back-EMF.

If you define the motor speed by generating a fixed frequency, then as JonRB says, you must supply enough voltage to overcome the sum of:
V1 = Kv * actual motor speed
V2 = IR loss from the motor resistance and the torque required to overcome friction and load resistance
V3 = IR loss from the torque required to accelerate the rotor + load if actual speed falls short of driving frequency.

Just as Kv = Speed / Voltage. the torque constant Ki = Torque / Current.

In SI units, Ki is simply 1/Kv : non-SI users have to remember a funny conversion number (which I've forgotten) as well as which of oz, lbs, feet, inches it refers to, or look it up in a textbook.

So, given Kv, you can compute Ki, and therefore V2 and V3 for both components of motor current I.

Driving a BLDC from a fixed frequency, V3 is critical : if the frequency is too high or the supply voltage too low, the motor simply won't start, so it's normal to ramp the frequency up until the desired speed is reached.

Then if the driving voltage is fixed, and higher than V1 + V2 combined, the motor will run, but inefficiently, i.e. waste power at steady state (at constant speed V3 = 0) so for efficient operation you need to reduce driving voltage to V1 + V2 (usually via PWM).

This can get complicated, so most controllers operate as in Bruce's answer : motor speed is controlled by voltage, with the BLDC sensing either the phase of the back-EMF, or motor position separately via hall-effect sensors or rotary encoders, and controlling the commutation frequency to suit the actual speed.

Answer (score 2):

> So from what I've understood, the KV rating for a motor gives us the
>   rotor speed based on the voltage applied at the phase of the motor.

I think you mean **Kv** (lower case 'v') which is the motor's 'velocity constant'. This is the rotational velocity required to generate a Back-EMF of 1 Volt. If Kv is specified in rpm/V then multiplying Kv by the applied voltage gives you the rpm when Back-EMF equals the supply voltage, which is the fastest it can go on that voltage (any faster and it would be acting as a generator, not a motor).

A perfect motor will always spin at this rpm. A practical motor has resistance which reduces the effective supply voltage and causes it to run slower as current increases. When the motor is running free it only draws a small current to overcome internal losses, so the no-load rpm is generally only slightly lower than Kv*Vs.

> What I'm thinking is that the frequency commuting defines speed, but
>   the current/volts going through each coil defines the maximum
>   force/acceleration the rotor can be pulled with.

Primarily it is **Volts** which determines speed and commutation frequency. At start up the rotor is stationary and producing no Back-EMF, so current is limited only by resistance of the windings. This current produces torque which accelerates the rotor. As the rotor speeds up it produces Back-EMF, reducing voltage across the winding resistance and lowering current and torque. rpm stabilizes when torque drops to match frictional losses and shaft loading (leaving no excess torque for acceleration).

A sensorless BLDC controller constantly monitors the Back-EMF waveform and commutates at each zero crossing. Unlike an AC drive It does **not** set a frequency and force the motor to spin at that speed. The ESC generates its commutation frequency as a *reaction* to the speed the motor is already doing. Speed is controlled by varying the **voltage** applied to the motor (usually with PWM).

Commutation must necessarily be kept in sync with the rotation, so you could say that commutation frequency is 'defined' by force/acceleration of the rotor, which is in turn 'defined' by the motor constants Kv (velocity constant), Rm (resistance), and Io (no-load current). Using these constants you can calculate the expected rpm and current with any load.

Answer (score 0):

Frequency is the vastly dominant quantity

*Frequency*

A BLDC/BLAC machine is basically just Sync machines and thus the frequency of the rotor is proportional to the electrical stator frequency (constant of proportionality being the pole pair count.

*Voltage*

That said voltage is equally key because you need to be able to inject AC into the stator. With an increase in electrical frequency, the mechanical frequency increases which in turn increases the backEMF presented by the machine (where the constant of proportionality is Ke).

At some point you will run out of supply voltage to overcome the backEMF, the resistive drop & the inductive drop. With increase speed the amount of current required equally increases to overcome the drag torque. Add some mechanical load into the system and the inductive voltage drop is comparable to the backEMF

Comment: So, the KV rating is actually a BEMF related constant ?

Comment: Without specifics of the machine it's hard to say. The kV rating could very well be the insulation withstand rather than associated with rotor velocity. Frequency is the governing quantity, just terminal voltage is important

Comment: What KV rating are you talking about? I have 3 BLDC (servo) motors on my desk right now, the only voltage ratings are for the winding supply (480 VAC for one of them, and 120VAC for the other two), and the insulation class.  In any event, frequency is the only thing that determines speed of an AC/BLDC motor as long as it isn't overloaded.

Comment: There is confusion in these comments between kV and Kv. kV (kilovolts) may refer to an insulation withstand rating. Kv (voltage constant) in rpm/V (non-SI) or radians/sec/volt (SI) relates back EMF to rotational velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Every BLDC motor rotates   commuting (one of six) divided by number of poles divided by six.

A 6 poles motor makes one electrical rotation(six commuters) per one mechanical rotation.

A 12 pole motor makes two electrical rotation(six commuters) per one mechanical rotation.

A 24 pole motor makes four electrical rotation(six commuters) per one mechanical rotation